# What are the criteria that Windows uses to put the system state on idle?

Tags: windows, scheduled-tasks

I'm looking that there are some tasks that are embedded with Windows that runs when system goes to idle state (such as Scheduled Defrag, System Restore, DefenderScan and RegistryBackup).

However, even if I leave the system stopped for such as 3 or 4 minutes, I don't see any of there tasks start to running them job.

*What are the criteria that Windows uses to put the system state on idle?*

Comment: You had accepted Mehrdad’s answer, but I don’t think it actually answered the question does it? Even in the original [revision](http://superuser.com/revisions/284828/1), you asked what *criteria* it uses to determine when the system is idle, which I interpret as meaning whether Windows examines mouse and keyboard input, CPU load, network activity, video rendering, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`SYSTEM_POWER_POLICY`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa373225.aspx) structure contains an `IdleTimeout` field and an `IdleSensitivity` field, each of which are as described as I've copied below:

> **IdleTimeout**:
>   The time that the level of system activity must remain below the idle detection threshold before the system idle timer expires, in seconds.
>
> **IdleSensitivity**:
>   The level of system activity that defines the threshold for idle detection, expressed as a percentage.

So it means as long as the system activity is below `IdleSensitivity` for at least a period of time equal to `IdleTimeout`, it is considered idle.

How you actually read/write those values without writing a program, I have no idea, sorry. :(

Answer (score 3):

There's a DWORD in the registry at `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\SchedulingAgent\MinutesBeforeIdle`. Its default value is 15.

There's also a command to force idle tasks to run:

```
rundll32.exe advapi32.dll,ProcessIdleTasks
```

Comment: Is there any other keys that I can edit in addition to 'MinutesBeforeIdle'? There is no items in the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\SchedulingAgent\ in regedit. It's empty. I would like to see all the items list so that I can insert that I need.