# How to change idle criteria for windows10 so idle can be triggered at the system resource level I usually idle at?

Tags: windows, task-scheduler

I learned that there is a property in Win10 to change sensitivity [What are the criteria that Windows uses to put the system state on idle?](https://superuser.com/questions/284828/what-are-the-criteria-that-windows-uses-to-put-the-system-state-on-idle)
also I learnt that there is certain percentage resource is been use to determine if an idle state is triggered.
My problem is, my idle state never triggered because my memory usage always at around 20% even when I am not using anything while CPU, GPU, disk all below 5%. I say never trigger, because I created a task to be triggered when idle state last for 2 min. still nothing happen, the app did not open.

How can I do to property trigger idle state for win10 for my case? is there other ways?

Example of my regular "IDLE" state for my PC

[image]

Comment: **This is wrong :** "idle" has nothing to do with RAM usage, but everything to do with user interaction and CPU usage. You should try to find which program uses continuously the CPU and doesn't let Windows enter the idle state.

Comment: How have you defined the scheduled task? Screenshots will be best.

Comment: @harrymc I added screenshot

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are not the first. https://superuser.com/a/285031
(Posting this as an answer cause I cannot comment yet. Anyhow, seems doable but messy).

A much simpler way would be to write a program that triggers idle state (`rundll32.exe advapi32.dll,ProcessIdleTasks`) whenever 20% usage of memory is detected.

Edit:
I wrote a code example of the idea. Basically you need to constantly read the memory usage and when you hit your minimum trigger once the IDLE command until next time (which would be under your conditions. I went with 'until mouse movement is detected, then restart the constant checking'). It is usable now but has a lot of room for improvement of course as it was just a sketch/concept for you to take it off and suite it for yourself. See the code here - https://github.com/ElayHadad/TriggerIdleState

Comment: that's the same post I referred to in the question though... I know that post, but that's not exactly a executable option...

Comment: Would you elaborate how to "write a program that triggers idle state (rundll32.exe advapi32.dll,ProcessIdleTasks) whenever 20% usage of memory is detected."? Then this answer will be extremely meaningful :) if you know how to write a shell script ... listen to this ... state?

Comment: Please give a concrete answer. Throwing around unimplementable ideas is not an answer.

Comment: @harrymc I gave you an answer and elaborated with a code. There’s a command to trigger IDLE state, so just write a program that runs in the background and constantly reads the RAM usage, when it hits your minimum trigger once the command and wait till next time. I even bothered to give you an example of the code, you are welcome to improve and finish it or write your own in your preferred language.

Comment: @harrymc Finished for you the code. Now it's useable, yet still a lot of room for improvements of course but you can do it to fit it for yourself however you like.

Comment: I'm not the poster...

Comment: xD lol. Wow I didn't even notice. @Ezeewei look on edited answer please see if it suites you better now :)

Comment: @WillingMost7 Its really nice! sry I did not get on SO until now! But I have issue running the code. how exactly "start" the app you wrote? lol I do not see any shell script or anything or .exe to execute things. also how do I stop this app after I started it?

Comment: @Ezeewei in the GitHub page of the application there’s a release, download from there the exe file I attached. In the application enter the minimum percentage of RAM usage you want the IDLE state to activate on and the amount of time you didn’t move your mouse and press start, the application will constantly run (minimize to run in background) and will activate IDLE state when meeting the requirements. Once IDLE state is activated, the application would stop until mouse is moved again, then will look again when to activate IDLE state. Place the exe anywhere and run it, there’s also an auto run